# Transparent LiveConnect OAuth 2.0 authentication possible?

Tags: oauth, onedrive, live-connect-sdk

I am currently working on an application that allows users to upload/download files. My company wants to have user files stored in their One Drive and not on our server. The only problem with this is that we want to avoid double authentication in order to access their OneDrive account.

For example we have *n* users associated with an organization. This organization has a single OneDrive account that all of the users will share (legal?). Once a user authenticates to our application, the idea is to have our application sign them in without user interaction by using the Live API so that they may access their organizations files.

**Do we have to authenticate every time we wish to use this service or just once?**

It's not a big deal for us to do this once for every organization when setting up their account but a requirement is to avoid double authentication. We want the OneDrive storage to be transparent to the user.

**Does this violate any of Microsoft's Terms and Conditions?**

Thanks! Any input is appreciated as I've never worked on a cloud based application before. If OneDrive isn't a viable solution are there any other recommended services my company could look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consumer OneDrive isn't intended for business use and sharing a single OneDrive account for multiple people isn't recommended either.  You should look into OneDrive for business for your scenario: https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-us/business/.

OneDrive for Business uses the SharePoint developer APIs: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2013/08/13/access-skydrive-pro-using-the-sharepoint-2013-apis.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I found that the Box API does not support a grant type of passworrd. Neither does OneDrive or DropBox. Without this grant type it is impossible to sent a username and password to log a user in.